# jQuery regular post WITHOUT Ajax

Tags: jquery, post

I thought this would be quite simple but the documentation doesn't point me to any solution. I am working on an editor. While i am using $.ajax for saving multiple forms at once i would like to perform the same post but with a complete page reload. how can i achieve that?

**Trigger Preview BTN -> Collect Forms -> Regular post to preview.php -> Render preview.php**

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is to just use a normal `<form>` and a redirect from the server-side.  Just use one `<form>` with all your inputs, no need for JavaScript at all.

---

If you need to *move* the elements in preparation for submission (since `<form>` elements can't be validly nested) then on the jQuery side all you need is to copy the elements into your single `<form>` (they should have unique names unless you want overlap), like this:

```
<form id="bigForm" method="post"></form>
```

Then in jQuery when you want to submit:

```
$("form :input").appendTo("#bigForm");
$("#bigForm").submit();
```

Comment: hehe yes i shouldnt use js if its not necessary... Didnt see the most simplest solution $('form').submit()... So is it true that i need to append "action=preview.php" to each form and $('form').submit() sends them all at once to preview.php... Will give that a try... Thank you!

Comment: @Bosh - That won't work for submitting *multiple* forms, rather structuring your page to only use one form initially :) For the others that you're submitting via AJAX you could have `<div>` containers for example, and just use `$("#thatDiv :input").serialize()` to get their data.

Comment: .. Ok that's what i am already doing on save. So what i am trying now is to append the serialized data to a one-field form and perform a regular submit for the preview... Thank you! Yes i really would have liked to structure the document to hold one form only but in that case i prefer to stick to multiple forms. ;-) thanks!

Comment: This approach was used to create jQuery.form() or $.form() in [jQuery post request (not Ajax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583703/jquery-post-request-not-ajax)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be elegant solution. Suppose I have some dynamic data, and I want to post it (no ajax). Your suggestion offers to generate multiple hidden inputs in form and then ".submit()" it. Is it really best solution?

Answer (score 2):

But if you still want to control this in Javascript, then you can simply reload page after $.post request is done or use $('form').submit(); so initiate normal submiting.

Comment: thank you... but reloading the page afterwards again doesn't look very efficient.