# JavaScript generate Rails collection form from checkboxes and Submit (non-AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm building filters for a collection of Objects. I can't have a form over the whole page because I have smaller AJAX forms within the content and Rails doesn't allow forms inside forms.  So I'm selectivng multiple profiles just fine in jQuery like so:

```
$(".profile-check:checked")
```

So now this is fine.  But I want to do the following without a form.

```
<%= form_tag profile_ids_profiles_path, id: 'profile[profile_ids]', method: :patch do %>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <%= select_tag 'profile[command]', options_for_select(['delete']), include_blank: true, class: 'form-control input-group filters-select' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'submit', class: 'form-control input-group-addon btn filters-submit' %>
  </div>

<%# EACH profile has this %>
<%= hidden_field_tag "profile[profile_ids][]", '' %><%= check_box_tag "profile[profile_ids][]", profile.id, nil, class: "profile-check" %>

<% end %>
```

So I need to know how to generate the form params to send to Rails in the normal manner.  Not with AJAX.  A standard form submission without the HTML form.  Only the params built within JavaScript/jQuery or CoffeeScript.

The params need to have the ID of the profile with the action being performed.

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"...",
>   "profile"=>{"command"=>"delete",
>   "profile_ids"=>["672", "674"]}}

### Half solved:

Here's the JavaScript to create these exact parameters:

```
var formSend = new Object;
formSend["utf8"] = "✓";
var csrfName = $("meta[name='csrf-param']").attr('content');
var csrfValue = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content');
formSend[csrfName] = csrfValue;
formSend["profile"] = new Object;
formSend["profile"]["command"] = "delete";
formSend["profile"]["profile_ids"] = $(".profile-check:checked").map(
  function(){return this.value;}
).get();
JSON.stringify(formSend);
```

How do I send this data with a click as parameters for a regular form submission.  Not AJAX/JS type submission, so that the server receives what it would expect from a normal web form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the 2nd half of the answer here: [jQuery post request (not Ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284150/1500195).  [Jeremy Banks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) gave some code he wrote which writes out an entire form from JSON and submits it.  I've tested it and it works.

Here is the working code:

```
jQuery(function($) { $.extend({
  form: function(url, data, method) {
    if (method == null) method = 'POST';
    if (data == null) data = {};

    var form = $('<form>').attr({
      method: method,
      action: url
     }).css({
      display: 'none'
     });

    var addData = function(name, data) {
      if ($.isArray(data)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var value = data[i];
          addData(name + '[]', value);
        }
      } else if (typeof data === 'object') {
          for (var key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              addData(name + '[' + key + ']', data[key]);
            }
          }
      } else if (data != null) {
        form.append($('<input>').attr({
          type: 'hidden',
          name: String(name),
          value: String(data)
        }));
      }
    };

    for (var key in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        addData(key, data[key]);
      }
    }

    return form.appendTo('body');
  }
}); });
function filterCheckboxes(route, thing, cmd) {
  var formSend = new Object;
  formSend["utf8"] = "✓";
  formSend["_method"] = "patch";
  var csrfName = $("meta[name='csrf-param']").attr('content');
  formSend[csrfName] = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content');
  formSend[thing] = new Object;
  formSend[thing]["command"] = cmd;
  formSend[thing][thing + "_ids"] = $("." + thing + "-check:checked").map(
      function () {
        return this.value;
      }
  ).get();
  $.form(route, formSend, 'POST').submit();
}
```

And in the view:

```
<%= content_tag 'span', 'delete', class: 'filter-delete', onclick: "filterCheckboxes('#{profile_ids_profiles_path}', 'profile', 'delete')", style: 'cursor:pointer;' %>
```

I did end up needing to add `formSend["_method"] = "patch";` since my routes have the method as PATCH.  But it works well ^_^.